# Multilanguage supported programme codding methods in c#

Tags: c#, .net, config, multilingual, resx

I want to create a program that support multilanguage in C#. But I need that the program should take the content of languages by using a text file(or .resx file, config file). I need that when I changed the meaning of one word from a text file, I must see the changes in the program without compiling .exe file.
How can I achieve this?
Thank you.

Comment: When would you ever need to change the meaning of a word? Either you discover ways to patch your compiled exe or you store everything in a database which would be very much overkill and costly imo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is called `[Internationalization (I18N)][1]`.

You should take a look into this [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1021kkz0(v=vs.71).aspx)

Also here's an example taken from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1129152/3754167) post:

```
 public class HelloWorld
{
    public CultureInfo CultureInfo { get; private set; }

    public HelloWorld()
    {
        CultureInfo = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture;
    }

    public HelloWorld(string culture)
    {
        CultureInfo = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo(culture);
    }

    public string SayHelloWorld()
    {
        return Resources.ResourceManager.GetString("HelloWorld", CultureInfo);
    }
}


[TestFixture]
public class HelloWorldFixture
{
    HelloWorld helloWorld;

    [Test]
    public void Ctor_SetsCultureInfo_ToCurrentCultureForParameterlessCtor()
    {
        helloWorld = new HelloWorld();
        Assert.AreEqual(helloWorld.CultureInfo, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture,
            "Expected CultureInfo to be set as CurrentCulture");
    }

    [Test]
    public void Ctor_SetsCultureInfo_ToAustralianCulture()
    {
        helloWorld = new HelloWorld("en-AU");
        Assert.AreEqual(helloWorld.CultureInfo.Name, "en-AU",
            "Expected CultureInfo to be set to Australian culture");
    }

    [Test]
    [ExpectedException(typeof(ArgumentException))]
    public void Ctor_ThrowsException_InvalidCultureName()
    {
        helloWorld = new HelloWorld("Bogus");
    }

    [Test]
    public void SayHelloWorld_ReturnsFallbackResource_OnUndefinedResource()
    {
        helloWorld = new HelloWorld("en-JM");
        string result = helloWorld.SayHelloWorld();
        Assert.AreEqual("Hello, World.", result, "Expected fallback resource string to be used");
    }

    [Test]
    public void SayHelloWorld_ReturnsAustralianResource_OnAustralianResource()
    {
        helloWorld = new HelloWorld("en-AU");
        string result = helloWorld.SayHelloWorld();
        Assert.AreEqual("G'Day, World.", result, "Expected australian resource string to be used");
    }
}
```